# how to use same instance of client for multiple message in Java Nio

Tags: java, client-server, nio

I am using Java Nio for Client server communication below are the code of client as well as server.

server:

```
public class BufferChannelExample {
    private static String clientChannel = "clientChannel";
    private static String serverChannel = "serverChannel";
    private static String channelType = "channelType";
    private static Selector selector = null;
    static BufferChannelExample bufferChannelExample = null;
    static int port1 = 1114;
    //static String localhost1 = "192.168.1.35";
    static String localhost1 = "192.168.1.88";
    ByteBuffer buffer;
    static String msgFromClient = "";
    static MsgSaver msgSaver;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

//      readFileChannel();
        //msgSaver = new MsgSaver();
        bufferChannelExample = new BufferChannelExample();
        serverSocketExample();

    }

    public static void writeToChannels() {

        if(selector == null)
            return;
        if(!selector.isOpen())
            return;
        Set multipleKeys = selector.keys(); 
        System.out.println("multipleKeys.size() : "+multipleKeys.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < multipleKeys.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("multipleKeys: "+multipleKeys.toString());
        }

        MulticastSocket multicastSocket = null;

        try {
            multicastSocket = new MulticastSocket(port1);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Iterator<SelectionKey> mkIterator = multipleKeys.iterator();
        while (mkIterator.hasNext()) {
            SelectionKey sKey = mkIterator.next();

            //                                  System.out.println("mk rAddr : "+((SocketChannel)sKey.channel()).getRemoteAddress().toString());
            //                                  if(sKey == key){
//          if((sKey.readyOps() & SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT) != SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT){
            if(((Map<?, ?>) sKey.attachment()).get(channelType).equals(
                    clientChannel)){
                 System.out.println("isWritable() --- > "+sKey.isWritable());
                 System.out.println("RemoteSocketAddress : "+((SocketChannel)sKey.channel()).socket().getRemoteSocketAddress());
                // write something to the new created client
                 CharBuffer buffer;
                 if(msgFromClient.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                 {
                  buffer = CharBuffer.wrap("Hello client new!!! ---stop");
                  System.out.println("if--");
                 }
                 else {

                     Iterator iter = multipleKeys.iterator();
                     while (iter.hasNext()) {
                       System.out.println(iter.next());
                     }

                      buffer = CharBuffer.wrap(msgFromClient);
                      System.out.println("else--");

                }

                //System.out.println("msgFromClient----"+msgSaver.getMsg());
                while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {

                    try {
                        ((SocketChannel)sKey.channel()).write(Charset.defaultCharset()
                                .encode (buffer)); 
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                buffer.clear();         
            }
            //                                  }
        }

    }

    private static void serverSocketExample() {
        ArrayList<String> remoteAddressArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        ServerSocketChannel channel1;
        try { 
            channel1 = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            channel1.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(localhost1, port1));
            channel1.configureBlocking(false);

            // create a selector that will by used for multiplexing. The selector
            // registers the socketserverchannel as
            // well as all socketchannels that are created
            selector = Selector.open();

            // register the serversocketchannel with the selector. The OP_ACCEPT
            // option marks
            // a selection key as ready when the channel accepts a new connection.
            // When the
            // socket server accepts a connection this key is added to the list of
            // selected keys of the selector.
            // when asked for the selected keys, this key is returned and hence we
            // know that a new connection has been accepted.
            SelectionKey socketServerSelectionKey = channel1.register(selector,
                    SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
            // set property in the key that identifies the channel
            // Map<String, String=""> properties = new HashMap<string, string="">();
            Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
            properties.put(channelType, serverChannel);
            socketServerSelectionKey.attach(properties);
            // wait for the selected keys
            for (;;) {
//              System.out.println("waiting for keys");
                // the select method is a blocking method which returns when atleast
                // one of the registered
                // channel is selected. In this example, when the socket accepts a
                // new connection, this method
                // will return. Once a socketclient is added to the list of
                // registered channels, then this method
                // would also return when one of the clients has data to be read or
                // written. It is also possible to perform a nonblocking select
                // using the selectNow() function.
                // We can also specify the maximum time for which a select function
                // can be blocked using the select(long timeout) function.
                if (selector.select() == 0)
                    continue;
                // the select method returns with a list of selected keys
                Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
                Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = selectedKeys.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    SelectionKey key = iterator.next();
//                  System.out.println("SelectionKey "+key.toString());
                    // the selection key could either by the socketserver informing
                    // that a new connection has been made, or
                    // a socket client that is ready for read/write
                    // we use the properties object attached to the channel to find
                    // out the type of channel.
                    if (((Map<?, ?>) key.attachment()).get(channelType).equals(
                            serverChannel)) {
                        // a new connection has been obtained. This channel is
                        // therefore a socket server.
                        ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key
                                .channel();
                        // accept the new connection on the server socket. Since the
                        // server socket channel is marked as non blocking
                        // this channel will return null if no client is connected.
                        SocketChannel clientSocketChannel = serverSocketChannel
                                .accept();

                        if (clientSocketChannel != null) {
                            // set the client connection to be non blocking
                            clientSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
                            SelectionKey clientKey = clientSocketChannel.register(
                                    selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ| SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                            Map<String, String> clientproperties = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            clientproperties.put(channelType, clientChannel);
                            clientKey.attach(clientproperties);

                            // write something to the new created client
                            CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.wrap("Hello client from server");
                            while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
//                              clientSocketChannel.write(Charset.defaultCharset()
//                                      .encode(buffer));

                                clientSocketChannel.write(Charset.defaultCharset()
                                        .encode(buffer));

                            }
                            buffer.clear();
                        }

                    } else {
                        // data is available for read
                        // buffer for reading
                        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(100); 
                        SocketChannel clientChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();    
                        int bytesRead = 0;
                        if (key.isReadable()) {
                            // the channel is non blocking so keep it open till the
                            // count is >=0
                            if ((bytesRead = clientChannel.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                                buffer.flip();
//                              System.out.println("message from client ---> "+Charset.defaultCharset().decode(
//                                      buffer));
                                msgFromClient = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(buffer).toString();
                                //msgSaver.setMsg(Charset.defaultCharset().decode(buffer).toString());
                                System.out.println("msgFromClient111----"+Charset.defaultCharset().decode(buffer).toString());
                                writeToChannels(); 
//                              if(th == null){
//                               th = new Thread(new NewRunnable());
//                               th.start();
//                              }

                                 buffer.clear();
                            }
                            if (bytesRead < 0) {
                                // the key is automatically invalidated once the
                                // channel is closed
                                clientChannel.close();
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    // once a key is handled, it needs to be removed
                    iterator.remove();

                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static Thread th = null;




}



}
```

Client:

public class ExampleClient2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
InterruptedException {
    int port = 1114;
    SocketChannel channel = SocketChannel.open();


    // we open this channel in non blocking mode
    channel.configureBlocking(false);
    channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.88", port));

    if(!channel.isConnected())
    {
        while (!channel.finishConnect()) {
            System.out.println("still connecting");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("connected...");


    while (true) {
        // see if any message has been received
        ByteBuffer bufferA = ByteBuffer.allocate(60);
        int count = 0;
        String message = "";
        while ((count = channel.read(bufferA)) > 0) {
            // flip the buffer to start reading
            bufferA.flip();
            message += Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bufferA);

        }

        if (message.length() > 0) {
            System.out.println("message " + message); 
            if(message.contains("stop"))
            {
                System.out.println("Has stop messages");
                //                  break;
            }
            else
            {
                // write some data into the channel
                CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.wrap("Hello Server stop from client2 from 88");
                while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                    channel.write(Charset.defaultCharset().encode(buffer));
                }
            }
            message = "";
        }

    }
}
```

}

here if i request to server from the same client twice , server will treat as a new client and create a new connections.How to detect that the message is coming from old client and do not need to create new connections.

thanks.

Comment: That's a silly way to do a non-blocking connect. You may as well do the connect in blocking mode, instead of smoking the CPU like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce HTTP Session management in your application and then track each client request based on the Session ID. Then you can have your application adapt to the situation.

If your server uses Servlet technology it will be much easier in adding a Servlet filter to intercept all incoming requests.

Comment: could you plz give me example on that.

Comment: If we use session id for track each client,will session terminate automatically after some time ?

Comment: To timeout session you will need to configure the <session-timeout> in the web.xml